# add layer mask for an android background image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, background, android

I am developer but I am in a situation I should act as a designer too for awhile..My question is I had an image I want to it to be a background for an app so I need to modify it to something like this app's background; it's not blur but a little darky..I need to know how to add that layer to the photo with simple tools?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to get a similar result is creating a gradient and placing a low opacity image over that background.

Create a colored gradient background using the Gradient Tool (G). I picked similar colors from your example image.

Purple: #423758

Turquoise: #124058

Place the image on top of the gradient background layer and set the blending mode to Luminosity. Lower the opacity of the photo to ~25%.

My layers

[image: image example layers]

Result

[image: end result]